# NCQ: what is a safe maximum of tags per drive

Tags: sata, hardware-raid

I have 16 Seagate Barracuda ES.2 drives in a RAID array.  If I select "tags per drive" parameter too high, I get "unexpected drive timeout" across all drives under heavy use.  What value should I select for reliable yet fast operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hardware dependent value, generally 8 seems safe, although 16 seems to be the upper bound on the drives we have.

I have looked at the data sheets and can't see the correct value. If you bought the whole thing as a system then the vendor should be able to supply the correct information

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion.  Vendor shipped this unit with 750GB Barracuda ES drives.  Unfortunately I did not write down the setting.  Now after upgrading to Barracuda ES.2 1000GB drives, I have no idea.  Testing shows 4 is OK, 32 is not OK.  More on it later in the day.

Comment: There is a drive I/O timeout setting.  By default it's set to 7.0 seconds.  Increasing the "tags per drive" value should be followed with an increased I/O timeout.  RAID manufacturer recommends 4 tags per drive for all SATA applications.